# How to get data according to group in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-8

Hello all I am using laravel and I am having some problem below is my array

```
[
    {
        "id": "375c572b-5c54-4c91-bb11-dda23bcf8052",
        "user_id": "a8dd7771-fc0e-46d3-b5a6-5a9ebaa89b9f",
        "group_id": "37b82ef4-c211-49a8-8e1c-a62c0f107219"
    },
    {
        "id": "809ee65e-e5b7-4519-ba7b-9d98ef0a4e3a",
        "user_id": "30517691-89b1-4247-9b74-522350e82622",
        "group_id": "37b82ef4-c211-49a8-8e1c-a62c0f107219"
    },
    {
        "id": "8d764272-3a5c-402f-8488-a641e3567e3e",
        "user_id": "a8dd7771-fc0e-46d3-b5a6-5a9ebaa89b9f",
        "group_id": "a24a9b00-a805-4142-99f4-3384bbb842f0"
    }
]
```

from the above array I want the result like below I want data with same group_id

```
[
    {
        "id": "375c572b-5c54-4c91-bb11-dda23bcf8052",
        "user_id": "a8dd7771-fc0e-46d3-b5a6-5a9ebaa89b9f",
        "group_id": "37b82ef4-c211-49a8-8e1c-a62c0f107219"
    },
    {
        "id": "809ee65e-e5b7-4519-ba7b-9d98ef0a4e3a",
        "user_id": "30517691-89b1-4247-9b74-522350e82622",
        "group_id": "37b82ef4-c211-49a8-8e1c-a62c0f107219"
    },
]
```

below is my code I tried but I am not getting result

```
$get_group_ids = DB::table('auc_chat_group_users')
                    ->select("id","user_id","group_id")
                    ->whereIn('user_id', $request->user_id)
                    ->orWhere('user_id',auth()->user()->id)
                    ->distinct('group_id')
                    ->groupBy("id","user_id","group_id")
                    ->orderBy('group_id')
                    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

[pluck()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck) should solve your problem

Comment: when I pass the user_id I get the data according to that I want to filter in that only suppose I paas three different user_id and I want to check if any group exists of that three user_id If I pass two I want to check for two

Comment: You can use `$groupIds = DB::table('auc_chat_group_users')->whereIn('user_id', $userIds)->pluck('group_id');`. Then, just use `$groupIds->count()`